# как разрабатывать telegrambot в России

Tags: telegram-bot, блокировки

Есть задача, пытаюсь реализовать в IDEA, но в самом начале в строке

```
telegramBotsApi.registerBot(Bot.getBot());
```

вылетает

> cannot resolve method getbot()

я подумал, что это связано с блокировкой и подключил nordVPN и ничего..
может я что-то делаю не так? посоветуйте решение проблемы или расскажите как вы пишите ботов

```
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(Bot.getBot());
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Метод для приема сообщений.
     * @param update Содержит сообщение от пользователя.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        String message = update.getMessage().getText();
        sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), message);
    }

    /**
     * Метод для настройки сообщения и его отправки.
     * @param chatId id чата
     * @param s Строка, которую необходимо отправить в качестве сообщения.
     */
    public synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId, String s) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(s);
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
           // log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Метод возвращает имя бота, указанное при регистрации.
     * @return имя бота
     */
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "*****"; 
    }

    /**
     * Метод возвращает token бота для связи с сервером Telegram
     * @return token для бота
     */
    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "*************";
    }
}
```

Comment: Блокировка ни при чем. У вашего объекта Bot нет метода getBot(). Добавьте кода.

Comment: добавил код, токен и имя поменял на "*", кстати с 'log'  cannot resolve symbol поэтому закоменчен

Answer (score 0):

вместо `Bot.getBot()` нужно написать `new bot()`